# How do I specify the "Trigger" value when starting a Google Cloud build using the projects.triggers.run API

Tags: google-cloud-build

In the [builds web UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds) there is a column labeled "Trigger". For automatically triggered builds it has the value "Push to branch-name branch". This was added recently and is very useful.

I want to add the same (or a similar value) that displays in that column when I use the `projects.triggers.run` API to run a trigger through the API. I looked at the help page [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run?apix_params=%7B%22projectId%22%3A%22engineering-199721%22%2C%22triggerId%22%3A%22b12b1066-9404-4a0b-8e80-58da65deb33c%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22repoName%22%3A%22github-infiotinc-infiot%22%2C%22commitSha%22%3A%229f8cabbfe88b86664cade54fdc7d9119c8d7fd14%22%7D%7D) but I cannot see a way. Is there a way that maybe is not documented yet?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to run that trigger would be to specify the Trigger ID. If you were to follow the trigger that links to, the url is in the form ".../cloud-build/triggers/$TRIGGER_ID/..", so you could use that to get the ID.

Best,

Ben

Comment: Of course I add a trigger id, otherwise the build would not start at all. The issue is that after the API triggered build starts, in the WEB UI we only see a dash. See attached image that clarifies.